# How to create custom pdf attachment in odoo10

Tags: odoo-10

When i click send by email button in sale order form.it automatically comes email template and qweb report attachment.it is a default process.in this process i need to customize the qweb attachment.

Answer (score 0):

You can edit the email template by finding you desired template in `Settings > Technical > Templates`.

If you want to change the qweb report, you can your report at this path `Settings > Technical > Reports`

Hope it works for you